# how safe is using the remote car toy from radiation

Tags: radiation

how safe is using the remote car toy from radiation, especially for kids,

The manufacturers claiming that it will be safe, but is that 100 % safe over kids.

Comment: The is no danger at all. RC devices operate at frequencies below visible light. Also, this question is probably considered off-topic as it does not ask for specific physics concepts.

Comment: migrate to skeptics.stackexchange, please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about safety. (Also, too old for migration by now)

Answer (score 1):

The remote car toy radiation are radio waves. So it's as dangerous as using a radio... The power of thoses emitter are not enought to be dangerous. So it's safe for your kids.